# Velocity template - message key instead the whole phrase with placeholders

Tags: java, velocity, email-templates

I have email template .vm which contains msg with message key from messages_en.properties:

```
#msg("email-body")
```

messages_en.properties has:

```
email-body = Hello, $name!
```

After:

```
private String buildMessage(String templateName, Properties properties, Locale locale) {

    Template template = getVelocityEngine().getTemplate(templateName);

    VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();

    for (String key : properties.stringPropertyNames()) {
        context.put(key, properties.getProperty(key));
    }

    context.put(LocaleDirective.MESSAGES_LOCALE, locale);

    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    template.merge(context, writer);

    return writer.toString();
}
```

I get:

```
Hello, $name!
```

And name isn't replaced with actual value.

What's the best way to manage phrases in email template? I want to put only message key in the template, not the whole phrase with placeholder.

Answer (score 1):

Use [evaluate](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/user-guide.html#evaluate) directive for substitute variable inside of other variable:

```
import org.apache.velocity.Template;
import org.apache.velocity.VelocityContext;
import org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeServices;
import org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeSingleton;
import org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.SimpleNode;

import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        RuntimeServices runtimeServices = RuntimeSingleton.getRuntimeServices();
        StringReader reader = new StringReader("#evaluate($email-body)");
        SimpleNode node = runtimeServices.parse(reader, "default");

        Template template = new Template();
        template.setRuntimeServices(runtimeServices);
        template.setData(node);
        template.initDocument();


        VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
        context.put("name", "Maxim");
        context.put("email-body", "Hello, $name!");

        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        template.merge(context, writer);

        System.out.println(writer.toString());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Hello, Maxim!
```

Comment: It works if all messages (in this case email-body) are put in VelocityContext but if I try to load with #msg and then #evaluate in .vm file it doesn't.

Comment: #evaluate('#msg("email-body")') will output Hello, $name!

Comment: As I understand the `msg` is a macros. So, the `evaluate` directive should be used inside of this macros I think.